# Neo4j slow creation method

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, graph-databases

In my Neo4j/Neo4j Spring Data application I have a following entities:

`VoteGroup` contains relationships `VOTED_ON` and `VOTED_FOR` to entities `Criterion` and `Decision` and list of `Vote`

```
@NodeEntity
public class VoteGroup extends BaseEntity {

    private static final String VOTED_ON = "VOTED_ON";
    private final static String VOTED_FOR = "VOTED_FOR";
    private final static String CONTAINS = "CONTAINS";

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @RelatedTo(type = VOTED_FOR, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Decision decision;

    @RelatedTo(type = VOTED_ON, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Criterion criterion;

    @RelatedTo(type = CONTAINS, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Set<Vote> votes = new HashSet<>();

    private double avgVotesWeight;

    private long totalVotesCount;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;
        VoteGroup voteGroup = (VoteGroup) o;
        if (id == null)
            return super.equals(o);
        return id.equals(voteGroup.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id != null ? id.hashCode() : super.hashCode();
    }
.....

}
```

`Vote` entity looks like:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Vote extends BaseEntity {

    private final static String CONTAINS = "CONTAINS";
    private final static String CREATED_BY = "CREATED_BY";

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @RelatedTo(type = CONTAINS, direction = Direction.INCOMING)
    private VoteGroup group;

    @RelatedTo(type = CREATED_BY, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private User author;

    private double weight;

....
}


public class BaseEntity {

    private Date createDate;

    private Date updateDate;

    public BaseEntity() {
    }

    public Date getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }

    public Date getUpdateDate() {
        return updateDate;
    }

    public void setUpdateDate(Date updateDate) {
        this.updateDate = updateDate;
    }

}
```

also. I use Neo4j hook based on BaseEntity:

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.example")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Neo4jConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration implements BeanFactoryAware {
    ...

    /**
     * Hook into the application lifecycle and register listeners that perform
     * behaviour across types of entities during this life cycle
     * 
     */
    @Bean
    protected ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent<BaseEntity>> beforeSaveEventApplicationListener() {
        return new ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent<BaseEntity>>() {
            @Override
            public void onApplicationEvent(BeforeSaveEvent<BaseEntity> event) {
                BaseEntity entity = event.getEntity();
                if (entity.getCreateDate() == null) {
                    entity.setCreateDate(new Date());
                } else {
                    entity.setUpdateDate(new Date());
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

...

```
}
```

in order to make a vote, I have implemented following method `VoteGroupDaoImpl.createVote`:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class VoteGroupDaoImpl implements VoteGroupDao {

    @Autowired
    private VoteRepository voteRepository;

    @Autowired
    private VoteGroupRepository voteGroupRepository;

    @Override
    public Vote createVote(Decision decision, Criterion criterion, User author, String description, double weight) {
        VoteGroup voteGroup = getVoteGroupForDecisionOnCriterion(decision.getId(), criterion.getId());
        if (voteGroup == null) {
            voteGroup = new VoteGroup(decision, criterion, weight, 1);
        } else {
            long newTotalVotesCount = voteGroup.getTotalVotesCount() + 1;
            double newAvgVotesWeight = (voteGroup.getAvgVotesWeight() * voteGroup.getTotalVotesCount() + weight) / newTotalVotesCount;
            voteGroup.setAvgVotesWeight(newAvgVotesWeight);
            voteGroup.setTotalVotesCount(newTotalVotesCount);
        }
        voteGroup = voteGroupRepository.save(voteGroup);

        return voteRepository.save(new Vote(voteGroup, author, weight, description));
    }
...

}
```

and

```
@Repository
public interface VoteGroupRepository extends GraphRepository<VoteGroup>, RelationshipOperationsRepository<VoteGroup> {

    @Query("MATCH (d:Decision)<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(vg:VoteGroup)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c:Criterion) WHERE id(d) = {decisionId} AND id(c) = {criterionId} RETURN vg")
    VoteGroup getVoteGroupForDecisionOnCriterion(@Param("decisionId") Long decisionId, @Param("criterionId") Long criterionId);

}
```

Right now, method `VoteGroupDaoImpl.createVote` works really slow with a huge latency .. what can be a reason of that ?

**ADDED PROFILE output**

for

```
MATCH (d:Decision)<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(vg:VoteGroup)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c:Criterion) WHERE id(d) = {decisionId} AND id(c) = {criterionId} RETURN vg
```

Cypher version: CYPHER 2.2, planner: COST. 33 total db hits in 181 ms.

[image]

**PROFILE Java code:**

[image]

**Rich profiler information:**

[HTML page with profiler information](http://www.thedownloadplanet.com/files/cpu-live.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm moved to new Neo4j 2.2.4 and SDN 3.4.0.RC1 and the issue disappeared

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas that may help:

1. Execute the query:

   `MATCH (d:Decision)<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(vg:VoteGroup)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c:Criterion)` `WHERE id(d) = {decisionId} AND id(c) = {criterionId} RETURN vg`

from the web interface or the console and check how it behaves. Try for the same ids you use in the app. Check what is the execution time.

2. Has VoteGroup numerous relations to Votes? If yes, can you remove:

   `@RelatedTo(type = CONTAINS, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
   private Set<Vote> votes = new HashSet<>();`

and keep information about relation on the Vote side only? Can you check the performance after that change?

3. Can you use some kind of a profiler tool to identify the exact place of performance problems? Right now it may be still difficult to guess...
4. Does the code behave as it should? Don you have any duplicates in the DB? Maybe you have bugs in your hashCode/equals methods that cause much more changes in the DB than there really should be?

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I have performed this query directly on Neo4j db and it works pretty fast.. Something wrong in my code. Also, when I don't use getVoteGroupForDecisionOnCriterion() method everything also works  fast.. What can be wrong with this method ?

Comment: I have removed `@RelatedTo(type = CONTAINS, direction = Direction.OUTGOING) private Set<Vote> votes = new HashSet<>();` - nothing changed

Comment: Exact place of performance problems is a following line -  `VoteGroup voteGroup = getVoteGroupForDecisionOnCriterion(decision.getId(), criterion.getId());`

Comment: Does the code behave as it should? - yes. l have also added my  hashCode/equals to VoteGroup in my question body

Comment: I have also added Java code profile information.. It shows that `getVoteGroupForDecisionOnCriterion` method performs really slow..

Comment: To be honest, looks really strange... And seems like not a problem with your code, but the code of "getVoteGroupForDecisionOnCriterion" generated for you by SDN. It is based on the query that has no performance problems by itself, you have no @Fetch annotations flying around the code, so I have no idea. Maybe paste the code of your superclass (BaseEntity) just to check if nothing wrong going there, or just wait for some Neo4j guru to help you, I feel helpless...

Comment: Thanks, I have added my BaseEntity class

Comment: maybe something wrong with transactions.. but how to check it..

Comment: I doubt that, but you may try to remove @EnableTransactionManagement and check if starting transactions manually with your GraphDatabaseService will change anything ...

Comment: One more idea - can the reason be in intensive write/read operations of VoteGroup nodes during the data import process ?

Comment: I also added HTML page with full profiler information

Answer (score 1):

You could try to reformulate the *getVoteGroupForDecisionOnCriterion* query as follows, in order to avoid the cartesian product:

```
MATCH (d:Decision) WHERE id(d) = {decisionId}
WITH d MATCH (c:Criterion) WHERE id(c) = {criterionId}
WITH d,c MATCH d<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(vg:VoteGroup)-[:VOTED_ON]->c
RETURN vg
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. the performance is prety much the same ( Can the reason of it be in intensive write/read operations of VoteGroup nodes during the data import process ?

Comment: no.. the method `getVoteGroupForDecisionOnCriterion` works slow even when the data was imported..

Comment: I also added HTML page with full profiler information