# Neo4j graph structure and performance issue

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, graph-databases

In my Neo4j/SDN application I run into performance issue with getting `VoteGroup` node that contains relationships to nodes - `Decision` and `Criterion`.

Details described here - [Neo4j slow creation method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31928321/neo4j-slow-creation-method)

In my application I have a list of `Vote` to each pair of `Decision` and `Criterion`. Each `Vote` has `weight`(`double`).

I need to perform some math based on average value for all `Vote` on each pair of `Decision` and `Criterion`.

Previously each `Vote` contained references to nodes - `Decision` and `Criterion`(like `VoteGroup` now).

In order to improve performance of getting average value for all `Vote` on each pair of `Decision` and `Criterion` I have introduced new intermediate node `VoteGroup`  that contains relationships to nodes - `Decision` and `Criterion`, precalculated `avgWeight` for this `Decision` and `Criterion` for all their `Vote` and also contains references to all these `Vote`.

Right now I have the performance issue when getting `VoteGroup`:

```
MATCH (d:Decision)<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(vg:VoteGroup)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c:Criterion)
WHERE id(d) = {decisionId} AND id(c) = {criterionId} 
RETURN vg
```

I have no idea what can be wrong.. May be I have created a wrong graph structure or something else..

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm moved to new Neo4j 2.2.4 and SDN 3.4.0.RC1 and the issue disappeared

Answer (score 0):

First of all - using internal `id` is not good idea. Consider to use your own `id` property (and not forget to add index on that).

Second - you can try to profile your query to find weak spots in your query ([info](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/how-do-i-profile-a-query.html)).
TL;DR; - add `PROFILE` before your query.

Third - you can rewrite your query to help database do it work in more optimal way. 
Example:

```
MATCH (d:Decision) WHERE id(d) = {decisionId}
MATCH (c:Criterion) WHERE id(c) = {criterionId}
WITH d, c
MATCH (d)<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(vg:VoteGroup)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c)
RETURN vg
```

Key part here is `WITH` keyword ([info](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-with.html)).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried this query however the performance is not significantly better. In the original question I have added all profile info - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31928321/neo4j-slow-creation-method  but I can't determine the reason of slow performance based on it. When I remove query for getting VoteGroup the rest of the logic works pretty fast..

Comment: Also data growth in the database slows down the performance of this query

Comment: @alexanoid how long it takes to run query from Neo4j browser?
How much data you have in database?

Comment: @alexanoid As I see query by itself is pretty fast - 181 ms (based on info from previous question).
This number depends on how much data is returned (serialized) to client. 

You should also checkout how Neo4j server is configured. Low Java heap size can reduce performance due to GC issues. 

Neo4j cache type/size also should be checked (be sure to use appropriate one, with decent amount of available memory).

Some links:  [Server perfomance](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-performance.html), [Performance guide](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/performance-guide.html)

Comment: Total nodes count: 397013
Decision nodes: 8346
Criterion nodes: 30526
VoteGroup nodes: 176864

Comment: query runs in the range of 20ms - 200ms

Comment: but the rest endpoint call takes 1.2s.. for example pure node create endpoint call takes 100-150ms..

Comment: @alexanoid How rest endpoint call time is measured? Try to make `curl` call to REST endpoint with your query and measure execution time.
[Curl call example](https://gist.github.com/FylmTM/04dae8d5c5819ea22e7a)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86764/discussion-between-fylmtm-and-alexanoid).